# python reorganize codes

Tags: python, refactoring

Sorry I dont know how to add a comment with the format, so I post another question with code here, as I am new to python, seems that there are many better ways to reorgnize the codes to make it better:

```
def min_qvalue(self):
    s = 0
    q = 1
    for i in range(len(self.results)):
        if self.results[i].score > s:
            s = self.results[i].score
            q = self.results[i].qvalue
    return q
```

For the above code, should not be the best piece, any improvements possible? thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the same code:

```
max_score_qvalue = max( (result.score, result.qvalue) for result in self.results)[1]
```

It makes pairs of the score and qvalue, finds the pair with the highest score (with `max`) and then gets the qvalue from it.

Actually, I wrote the above just because I keep forgetting that `max` takes a key function too:

```
max_score_qvalue = max(self.results, key=(lambda result: result.score)).qvalue
```

Also your function says min_qvalue but it computes one with the maximum score!

Comment: so the final functional style formula is


min_qvalue = lambda self: max(self.results,key = (lambda result:result.score)).qvalue

Comment: they go different directions, i.e. the lower the q-value, the higher the socre is

Comment: You can even get rid of the lambda by using operator.attrgetter("score") (though of course you need to import it)

Answer (score 1):

If you result list is mutable and you often have need to compute this, it's may be better to you [heap queue algorithm](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#module-heapq). There's sample code:

```
import heapq
class ResultManager(object):
    def __init__( self , results ):
        self.results = [( -result.score, result) for result in results]
        heapq.heapify( self.results )
    def append( self , result ):
        heapq.heappush( self.results , ( -result.score, result) )
    def getMaxScoreQValue(self):
        return self.results[0][1].qvalue
```